# DividerItemDecoration will not work no matter what I do

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

This is the code for setting the decoration :-

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.HORIZONTAL));
```

This is the xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:height="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
</shape>
```

I have tried setting the drawable using `DividerItemDecoration.setDrawable(Drawable drawable)`
and setting the `android:listDivider` item in my theme to point to the xml.

I have also tried setting the width to 1dp. Absolutely nothing works.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: don't use "recyclerView.getContext()". if you have activity then use "ActivityName.this" as context and if you use Fragment then use "getContext" as context.

Comment: @TakeInfo Just tried, did not work

Comment: What is the orientation of your RecyclerView? I would try passing in the orientation of the RecyclerView when you set your divider.

Comment: Use LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL or RelativeLayout.HORIZOTAL which you use as root node in your xml file  instead of DividerItemDecoration.HORIZONTAL

Comment: android:listDivider is used for ListView, it's not suitable for RecycleView

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the orientation of your RecyclerView is default(vertical), then you should use **DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL** instead.

I've just tried creating a RecyclerView with a default DividerItemDecoration and your xml resource, and everything worked

[image]

Comment: That did it! I mistook the orientation parameter to be the orientation I want the line to be and not the RecyclerView orientation as it should be. Thanks a ton :)